# Update lambda function code (created using the console) using serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have created a lambda function from the console - test_lambda_function and updated it with sample code as shown below:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I would like to now update the function's code using the serverless framework. PFA my serverless template.

I am trying to deploy the template using the following command:

`sls deploy`

I am getting an error that says the lambda function already exists and the command is failing

Can anyone help me out here. I have created a lot of lambda functions earlier and now I wish to use this serverless framework in my CI/CD pipeline

Thanks in advance!